# IOS development, problems with setting uibutton image, very weird in my eyes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Can any one tell me what is wrong with this code?

Only the else part is not working, if I have an image for the note, every thing is working just perfect, but when i am trying to show the "no_image" image, i just don't see it (there is not error). Looks like a "nil", but the image is in the project, for sure. i am using the same image in other places and other methods and it is working over there. just in the UIButton not working.

```
//setting the note header data
if (note.imageThumb) {
    [photoButton setImage:note.imageThumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {
    [photoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Thank you,
Erez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

When using setImage, I am getting nil.
When using setBackgroundImage I am getting the image.

Used the background, It is great for this, and doesn't matter in this case, I think the issue is with the size of the button and the size of the thumb.

Thank you all,
Erez

Answer (score 2):

Try including an `NSLog` statement in your `else` code, to see if it is being called or not.  It is possible that the `if` statement is returning TRUE, if note.imageThumb exists, even if it is empty.

The line of code in the `else` statement looks good to me, so I'd definitely start with checking which part is actually being called.

Comment: Thank you, this is not the answer for my problem, but it is the right answer for every thing.